# Waiting for async function to finish

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem, I want to make the asynchrnous function to finish first before going to the next one. Why? Because the value of the function is needed to the next line of code.

I tried, await, `wait()`, `RunSynchronous` but it is not working. 
It still proceeds to execute other lines of code.

This is my code: It is the default Login for `ASP.NET MVC5` but what I want to do is change the redirect depending on the user.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {     
                          SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                         RedirectToLocal(LogInRedirect());
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

I have a custom parameter called UserDepartment and I can only retrieve it after SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe); finish executing.

This is the code for SignInAsync

```
    private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
         AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity); 
    }
```

What should I do to achieve my goal that SignInAsync should finish first before proceeding to other line of code.

EDIT: 
So await works, but there is another problem. 
SignInAsync is not yet finish but it already return that it is completed. By finish I mean the execution of code, I trace the execution but there are times that  AuthenticationManager.SignIn is not yet finish but still return it is

Comment: await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe)

Comment: if you need the value to move in to the next one, why is it async?

Comment: MVC Default uses async methods

Comment: @FranzJustinA.Buenaventura is `AuthenticationManager.SignIn` a synchronous process though?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `await` the result of the `SignInAsync` call

```
await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
...
```

You internally `await` the result of the `UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync` method so that will block until that result returns inside the `SignInAsync` method. However, without awaiting the call to `SignInAsync` itself, the code won't block which is why the next line is called immediately.

Comment: Cannot await 'void'
Edit: my mistake there is Wait() on that the real error is
Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable 

The return of SignInAsync is just Task

Comment: @FranzJustinA.Buenaventura sorry didn't realise it was a `void` return type, just remove the `var result = ` part (see update).

Comment: No it still runs async I dont know why

Comment: @FranzJustinA.Buenaventura You mean runs synchronously, not async. Your sure this isn't working? Looks correct to me.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, question: the await parameter is only for the next lin of function or all remaining?